# Search and Replace tab key in Openoffice

Tags: openoffice.org

I haved wrote a next code to find a replace strings, I need to use this code to find "=" and replace with tab key, I trying with "\t" but this doesn't work, Could you help me please? What is a character tab key for use in macro of openoffice?

```
Public Function findReplace(oDoc As Object, findStr As String, replaceStr As String) As Integer 
   oSearch = oDoc.createSearchDescriptor
   oSearch.searchAll = False
   oSearch.SearchString = findStr
   oSearch.ReplaceString = replaceStr
   oDoc.replaceAll(oSearch)
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

[alfetta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2991542/alfetta) is right - just enable RegularExpression

```
  oSearch.SearchRegularExpression = TRUE
```

to have `\t` as `replaceStr` working, replacing with a Tab.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find a tab with Search and Replace using \t with "Regular Expressions" checked
after starting Find & Replace StrgF